# RTTI symbol not found for class ‘QtimerEvent’ error

Tags: qt, rtti, qtimer

I’m getting the min, max and value variables from my `changeProgressBarValue` function with a ‘for’ loop. When I check the flow with breakpoints I can’t find any problems in value appointment. Then I try to call this function from a timer event function which gets these variables from the `changeProgressBarValue` function once a second but I get an error stating `RTTI symbol not found for class ‘QtimerEvent’`. What could be the reason for this error message?

Comment: Which Qt version do you use? Do you compile it yourself from sources?

Comment: I'm using 4.7.3 version.